# Find a basis for V for $V=\{( x_1 , ... , x_n) \in K^n \mid x_1 +...+x_n =0\}$ .

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to find a basis for the set $V$, $V=\{( x_1 , ... , x_n) \in K^n \mid  x_1 +...+x_n =0\}$ .

Could anyone please explain the solution in the most simplistic way.

I thought the answer is just the set of ${e_1 ,..., e_n}$ but its not.

Comment: Could you include your definition of basis, and subspace, on your question for me please?

Comment: Sorry I mistyped the previous question, I know how to find the subspace. The basis is defined for the vector space V if the set of elements of V are linearly independent and span vector space V. I thought the answer will just be e=(0,0,0,...,n)

Comment: @Eoin: Really? What reason did you have to believe that John was using nonstandard definitions?

Comment: @EricStucky Just a way to write down the definition for themselves and possibly include what they have tried. He was getting massively downvoted for lack of information.

Comment: @Eoin: Fair enough. My apologies.

Comment: The OP has taken the step of [asking for guidelines at Meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/17286/11619), so I recommend giving the benefit of doubt. If only all new users asked, we would avoid a lot of unpleasantness. Of course, it would be even better if newcomers lurked for a while before asking their first question.

Answer (score 1):

$x_n = -x_1 - x_2 ..- x_{n-1}$. Thus:

$$(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) = (x_1,x_2, \dots,x_{n-1}, -x_1 - x_2...- x_{n-1})$$ $$= x_1(1,0,...,0,-1) + x_2(0,1,...,0,-1) + ....+ x_{n-1}(0,0,...,1,-1)$$

From this we can "see" the basis:

$\mathcal{B} = \{b_1,b_2,...,b_{n-1}\}$, with $b_k = (0,0,...,1,0,...,0,-1)$ with the $1$ is at the $k$-th position.

Answer (score 1):

To make things easier do it for n=2,3,4;

for n=3;
$x_1+x_2+x_3=0$

$\rightarrow x_3=-(x_1+x_2)$

so the basis becomes $\{(1,0,-1),(0,1,-1)\}$

For n=4,trying same way
The basis is $\{(1.0,0,-1),(0,1,0,-1),(0,0,1,-1)\}$

Thus in your case the basis becomes $B=\{b_1,b_2,....b_{n-1}\}$

where $b_k=(0,0,0....1,0,0,....-1)$
where 1 is in the $k^{th}$ position.